# Does anyone knows why my Delphi FMX app opens from beginning after a while?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am new in Delphi and start using Delphi 10.4.1 to develop Android apps. I use Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Light.

Unfortunately my apps starts from the beginning if I start using other apps or do some phone calls etc.
I tried to play with my phone settings to not the let my apps do battery optimized etc. but no use.
I compiled Debug - Release no chance at all.

I don't know if is there settings or something on my Delphi (I did try an Xamarin Apps, they keep stay exactly in the same screen even if I open it back after a day )

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: I did try SaveState event in delphi but looks like it is not stable. I did save the state of the which TabItem is active and tried to restore the same tabitem when I create the form , but no chance. With Xamarin it looks like SaveState event fires itself automaticly , thats why when I open the app even 2 days lates it stays as it was.

Comment: First fully read the help topics like _FireMonkey Save State_ then if you can't get something working post an MCVE showing what you tried, what you expected and what you actually got.

Comment: I did read all the help and topics and it looks like something simple turned into impossible as I still didn't get a comments or answer about it. I need to get back to the same screen if my app terminated by Android that's all.